# Problema con comillas dobles en string

Tags: java

Tengo una sentencia SQL que va a entrar por parámetros y va a ser almacenada en una variable tipo String. Cuando la sentencia es almacenada, por defecto, sus comillas dobles llevan por delante una `\` para poder almacenarlas como tal. Sin embargo, esto no me interesa, si no que lo que yo quiero es que, cuando la sentencia se almacene, se conserve íntegra la cadena de caracteres (lo cual no es posible en principio por las normas de declaración de un String).

Es decir, teóricamente, yo quiero esto

```java
String query = ""sentencia1"";
```

Y sin embargo, lo que obtengo realmente es esto

```java
String query = "\\"sentencia1\\"";
```

Podría hacer cambios en la variable a posteriori para "formatear" la sentencia, pero entonces ya se ha almacenado con esos símbolos adicionales, por lo que lo óptimo sería que ya se almacenara correctamente.

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener lo que busco, o algo parecido?

Comment: Aparte del problema de las comillas, parecería una práctica muy peligrosa lo que intentas hacer aquí. ¿Has oído hablar de la *inyección SQL*? Tu escenario parece perfecto para que los hackers ataquen el sistema en que será instalada tu aplicación. Y esos ataques pueden ir desde alterar, borrar, sustraer información, hasta ganar niveles de acceso en la base de datos que abrirían la puerta a que te cuelen archivos maliciosos en el sistema (sí, eso es posible, en algunos escenarios, desde una instrucción SQL). Quizá deberías pensar en usar consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 3):

Los caracteres de escape no se guardan como parte del String, es la forma que tiene Java de declarar que el siguiente caracter no tiene el significado estándar en el lenguaje.
Pasa exactamente lo mismo en Javascript, por ejemplo:

```js
const miString="hola";
const miStringConComillas="\"hola\"";
const miStringConOtrosCaracteresEscapados="\"En un lugar de \n \t La Mancha\"";

console.log(miString,miString.length);
console.log(miStringConComillas,miStringConComillas.length);
console.log(miStringConOtrosCaracteresEscapados,miStringConOtrosCaracteresEscapados.length);
console.log("Lista de caracteres:",
miStringConOtrosCaracteresEscapados.split("").toString());
```

#### Explicación alternativa:

Java (y cualquier otro lenguaje de programación, aquí uso Javascript por su inmediatez para ejecutar), cuando trabaja con caracteres, internamente usa números:

```js
const vocales ="aeiou";
const nuevaLinea = "\n";

function obtenerCodigos(str) {
  const codigos= [];
  for (let i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    codigos.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return codigos;
}

console.log(obtenerCodigos(vocales).toString());
console.log(obtenerCodigos(nuevaLinea).toString());
```

Pero puesto que escribir algo como

```java
   byte[] vocalesConNuevaLinea = {97,101,105,111,117,10};
   String texto = new String(vocalesConNuevaLinea);
```

sería muy incómodo, podemos usar algo más amigable:

```
String texto="aeiou\n";
```

Puesto que los Strings *clásicos* en Java no pueden ser multilínea (es una limitación del lenguaje, heredada de C y C++), el retorno de carro se representa con `\n`, del mismo modo que los caracteres no visibles se pueden representar usando su código Unicode en hexadecimal: `"\u000A"` (10 en decimal) es equivalente a "\n", `"\u0061"` (97 en decimal) es equivalente a `"a"`.

Nota: Java ahora tiene *String blocks*, usando `"""` como delimitador, que permite usar más caracteres sin tener que escaparlos:

```
public String getHtml() {
    return """
            <html>

                <body>
                    <span class="center">Ejemplo</span>
                </body>
            </html>""";
}
```

Comment: Siguiendo tu planteamiento, entonces puedo realizar cualquier modificación en el string (por ejemplo, partirlo en 2-3 partes), que Java no va a tener en cuenta esos símbolos en ningún momento?

Comment: He editado para poner otra explicación, pero puedes comprobar que `"\n".length()` es 1

Comment: @Pablolozano me parece muy detallada la respuesta, solo hacer una pequeña corrección. En `Java 13 y 14` se introdujo la posibilidad de bloques de texto multilínea como característica de prueba y se oficializo en `Java15`  [ejemplo](https://mkyong.com/java/java-multi-line-string-text-blocks/), se utiliza un texto entre triple comilla doble """Texto Multilínea"""

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Tienes razón! Aún no he trabajado con estas versiones y se me había olvidado esa novedad... es lo que tiene trabajar sólo con las versiones LTS, aún no he migrado a Java 17. Lo añadiré

Comment: Asumo que la triple comilla en Java funciona igual que otros lenguajes y mantiene la indentación del texto entre ellas, verdad?? Por lo que si quieres un bloque de texto sin indentación te tocaría "pegar" el texto a la izquierda, sacándolo del flujo de indentación del resto del código, no?

Comment: @Benito-B Correcto, se usan las primeras triples comillas como referencia para reducir la identación del resto de líneas